# Fundamental solution of the Laplace operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We know that in the entire plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ the fundamental solution of the Laplace operator is $$
G(x)=-\frac{1}{2 \pi} \log |x|,
$$
so we can find how $K_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}(x, y)=K(x-y)=\nabla^{\perp} G(x-y)$ behaves, where $\nabla^{\perp}=\left(\partial_{2},-\partial_{1}\right)$. But if instead of the entire plane we have a general connected set $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ how does $K_{\Gamma}(x, y)$ behave?
I'm looking for this because I want to find some estimates on $K_{\Gamma}(x, y)$.

Comment: What do you mean by “behave”? Also, what boundary conditions do you put on $\Gamma$?

Comment: I mean that the norm of K in the entire plane is C/|x| but I don't know how it goes K in a generic connected set of the plane when x tends to infinity

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the Green's function (for the Dirichlet problem) on the unit disc $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|<1\}$ (I will use complex numbers, but it can easily be rewritten with real numbers) which is given by
\begin{align}
G_D(z, z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left|\frac{1-z\bar z_0}{z-z_0} \right|.
\end{align}

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a simply connected proper region of the complex plane. By Riemann's mapping theorem, there exists a conformal transformation $f:\Gamma\rightarrow D$. In particular, we have that
\begin{align}
G_\Gamma(\zeta, \zeta_0) = G_D(f(\zeta), f(\zeta_0)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\log\left| \frac{1-f(\zeta)\overline{f(\zeta_0)}}{f(\zeta)-f(\zeta_0)}\right|
\end{align}
since conformal (analytic) mapping preserves "harmonicity" of harmonic functions.

You can choose some concrete $\Gamma$ and find estimates for $G_\Gamma$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is precisely what I wanted.

Comment: But this theorem works for D the unit disc, but not for the entire complex plane. I started from the entire real plane, how can I use this theorem in my case?

Comment: All I am considering is the Dirichlet problem on $\Gamma$. I thought that is what you want, to consider the Dirichlet problem on some connected domain.

Comment: Yes but my question started precisely from the entire plane, basically what I wanted is a generalization of K from the entire plane to a generic connected subset of the plane. You gave me an answer but you started from a complex disc and then you arrive to a generic connected set using the Riemann theorem. If you start from the generic complex plane you can't use the Riemann theorem and so you can't arrive to define G in that way. I hope that this is sufficient clear.

Comment: Why do you want to start from the entire plane? Are you  considering the Dirichlet problem on $\Gamma$ or are you consider the Poisson equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and want to find estimates for $K_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ but restricted to $\Gamma$?

Comment: because we know the explicit equation of the fundamental solution of the laplace operator only in the entire plane and it has the form that I wrote in the question.

Comment: We also know the explicit  fundamental solution for the laplace operator on the disk and that is what I have written.

Comment: Then the question you have posted is a little misleading. Since you wrote $K_\Gamma$, I interpreted it to mean the Green's function for $\Gamma$.

Comment: If you are interested in $K_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ but restricted to $\Gamma$ then just estimate $K_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ on $\Gamma$.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not interested in a restriction of $K_{\mathbb{R^2}}$ but i'm interested precisely in $K_{\Gamma}$, so yes i want the Green's function for $\Gamma$. Indeed what you wrote is what I needed. Sorry for the previous comment the answer is what I wanted.

Comment: Now the problem is, how $f$ modify the distance. I'm starting from $x$ I find $f(x)$ but how can I estimate the $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$?